# i need help returning the input of an array with the biggest sum

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, sum, return

The returned array should contain the three consecutive elements in the input array with the biggest sum. and I'm stuck? anyone help please?

```
public class Assigment4 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int [] setOfNum= {1,2,3,4};

}
public static int [] threeIntegers (int [] numbers){

    int [] arrayNew = new int [numbers.length-1];
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=0; i<3;i++){
    sum=sum+numbers[i];
    }
    if (sum>)//i got stuck here



}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work. You need two loops

```
public static int [] threeIntegers (int [] numbers){
    int max=0 //assuming array contains positive only
    int [] maxArray = new int [3];
    for(int j=0;j<numbers.length-2;++j){
      int sum=0;
      int [] newArray = new int [3];
      for(int i=0; i<3;i++){
        sum+=numbers[i+j];
        newArray[i]=numbers[i+j];
      }
      if (sum>max){
        max=sum;
        maxArray=newArray;
      }
   }

   return maxArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int [] threeIntegers (int [] numbers){
    int max=0;
    int [] maxArray = null;
    for(int i=0;i<numbers.length-3;++i)
    {
      int sum=numbers[i] + numbers[i+1] + numbers[i+2];
      if (sum>max)
      {
        max=sum;
        maxArray= new int[]{numbers[i], numbers[i+1], numbers[i+2]};
      }
   }

   return maxArray;
}
```